# positively homogeneous function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions

A function $f:X→\mathbb{R}$ is said to be positive homogeneous of degree $k\in\mathbb{R}$ if $f(tx)=t^kf(x)$ for every $x\in X$ and every $t\in\mathbb{R}_{++}$.

For $X=\mathbb{R}_+$, the sample example is: $f(x)=M.x^k$ where $M\in\mathbb{R}$

Can you give me another example?

Comment: I need an example in $\mathbb{R}_+$

Answer (score 3):

There are several classical economic functions that are known to be homogeneous of degree 1. First, we have the class of [CES production functions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_elasticity_of_substitution), where 
$$f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = C\cdot \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n \left(\frac{x_i}{a_i}\right)^r\right)^{\frac1r}.$$
You can verify that this function is 1-homogeneous. 
Other famous functions are $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \min_i x_i$, and $f(x_1,\dots,x_n) = \max_i x_i$.

Other more interesting functions would be network flow functions. Given a directed graph $\Gamma = \langle V,E\rangle$, define a function $\mathit{flow}: \mathbb{R}_+^E \to \mathbb R_+$, as $\mathit{flow}(w_e)_{e \in E}$ being the maximum flow over $\Gamma$ when the edge weights are $(w_e)_{e \in E}$. There are many more, but I hope that this gives you a general idea of where to find them.

Answer (score 2):

If $X = \mathbb R^3$, then $f(x,y,z)= |x^3 + x^2z + xyz-y^3|$ is an example with $k=3$.